# possible corruption of SQLite db file

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-net, computer-forensics

SQLite database .db file shows record exists when I open it in an ascii text editor. But there are 0 records when I open in sqlite browser or using client driver.  Table definition is still there.
If I run pragma integrity_check, result is ok.

Note: that table is created under main database.

Have you ever faced with this kind of problem?

Comment: [SQLite FAQ: I deleted a lot of data but the database file did not get any smaller. Is this a bug?](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q12)

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a record from a SQLite DB (and it's the same in many other DBs as well), the record isn't deleted right away from the database, but only marked as a deleted row. That's why you can still see it in a hex/text editor, although you cannot access it through SQL statements.

To remove the deleted rows from the DB and recover the disk-space you should use the [VACUUM](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) statement.